# Horrible performance on inverted Flatlist on Android, when a lot of text is on screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am building a chat app and since `React-Native` version `0.63`, I am having horrible performance when there are long texts involved on an inverted Flatlist, on **Android**.

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@divone/4c8d68) is a snack repro showcasing the issue (visible only when trying on a physical Android phone).

[I reported a bug for it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30034). It should be pretty flagrant for anyone who is building a chat app with an inverted Flatlist, but somehow I don't see this issue being talked about anywhere.

This made me think that maybe others have solved it somehow? If yes, how can I solve it too? It is making my app barely usable right now.

Comment: What do you mean by horrible performance? I have tested your snack on my android device and didn't feel any issue

Comment: From what I gathered, it seems that it only happens on certain devices. On my Pixel 4 with Android 11 the issue is very flagrant. May I ask what device you used?

Comment: I am using Samsung galaxy s7 edge.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by applying a style to the flatlist and the rendering view.
It is some kind of problem with android 11, since in previous versions this does not happen with the inverted lists.
add the style `scaleY: -1` to the flatlist and to the container of the view you are going to render, like this:

```
 return (
  <FlatList
    // ...
    style={{scaleY: -1}}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
      return (
        <View style={{scaleY: -1}}>
          {/* cell content */}
        </View
      );
    }}
  >
);
```

Comment: scaleY style does not work on react >0.70 - you can use rotate (however, this introduces problem with scroll bar being on the wrong side). Interesting discussion is here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30034

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `Flatlist` component has been written in a better way to have better performance than other list components like `ScrollView`. But you should consider there are few principles for a very long list like chat:

- **Unique Key**: For having unique keys to *cache* and *re-ordering* in the best way it is **YOU** to pass the unique key because `ReactJS` just use `item.key` and if it does not exist the `ReactJS` use `index` and it is the root of the performance issue, ***SO***, you should use a prop that name is [`keyExtractor`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor) and make a good function to produce unique keys.
- **Skipping The Measurement of Dynamic Content**: To avoid the re-calculating items measurements in every re-rendering you could use a prop that name is [`getItemLayout`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout) and pass the `width`, `height`, `offset`, `index` and etc. adding `getItemLayout` could help you to have a huge performance boost for a long lists with several items.
- **Determine Initial Items' Number**: You can determine a number of items to load and avoid showing the seen items, this could be a little tricky but I guess using [`initialNumToRender`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender) could help you for initilal loading, after initial you can trim the seen items that they are not in view screen.
- **Remove Clipped Items**: For this you can use the prop name that name is [`removeClippedSubviews`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#removeclippedsubviews) but care about it. maybe it has bug in some situations.

By my experinces, these ways can improve performance of the long lists. I hope these help you, and maybe there are some other tricks to have better performance.

Comment: Hello, I have already used all these tricks. As you can see in the snack, however, the most basic inverted Flatlist is enough to trigger the issue. It's just 30 blocks of text, with nothing fancy... so none of the options above really do anything to improve performance in this case.

Comment: @RyanPergent, I saw the Snack link but you didn't use `keyExtractor` or `getItemLayout`.

Comment: Yes, but I tried it before with no success. Also, I think `keyExtractor` is not necessary if the items have a "key" value, like in my snack. Furthermore, I believe that `keyExtractor` and `getItemLayout` are really useful when you have a large list with many items to render, right? This snack has only 30 items and no re-renders at all.

Comment: @RyanPergent, I test your snack code on my local, with larger text content that you intered in the Snack URL, but there is no issue on Android and iOS, I tested both of them.

Comment: From what I gathered, it seems that it only happens on certain devices. On my Pixel 4 with Android 11 the issue is very flagrant. May I ask what device you used?

Comment: The issue seems to happen on Samsung and Google Pixel devices with Android 11+